# Firefox createMediaStreamDestination bug using rtc?

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, html5-audio

I stream audio over rtc and want to mute and unmute the audio.

This works... but no gain control:

```
function(stream) { /* getUserMedia stream */
      console.log("Access granted to audio/video");
      peer_connection.addStream(stream);
}
```

This works on chrome but NOT on Firefox (with gain control)

```
function(stream) { /* getUserMedia stream */
  console.log("Access granted to audio/video");
  var microphone = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  gainNode = context.createGain();
  var dest = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
  microphone.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(dest);

  local_media_stream = dest.stream;
  peer_connection.addStream(local_media_stream);
}
```

I get no error and i hear no voice. 
When I send the gainNode to context.destination i can hear myself.

I think "context.createMediaStreamSource(stream)" is broken in any way.
Can anyone tell me why ? and how to fix this.

---

EDIT: So i checked the streams and:

```
stream //type: LocalMediaStream    
dest.steam //type: MediaStream
```

in Firefox! In chrome both are MediaStreams

Comment: What do FF return if you use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` instead of `navigator.getUserMedia`?

Comment: the same data types and the same result: no voice. But worth a try :)

Comment: Yeah, they probably just made that available and wired up the same code as with the old way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok thanks to @Ken Fyrstenberg I just tried the Firefox Nighly build. 
On the Nighly everythink works fine (as in Chrome). The data types are:

```
stream //type: LocalMediaStream    
dest.steam //type: MediaStream
```

as before, but I can hear the opponent and be able to mute the mic.

So I only have to wait for release :P

Answer (score 3):

To mute the audio you can enable/disable the track itself by doing:

```
stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;  // mutes
```

This won't solve the problem with the gain node, which is most likely a bug/limitation in Firefox at the moment (in which case we can only wait for a fix). But if the purpose is to (un)mute this should work (it also works with video tracks).

Comment: Sadly this inst working because type of stream is : LocalMediaStream and not MediaStream as in chrome. So it dont have the getAudioTracks() function. In chrome this works perfectly!

Comment: but smart way to mute :)

Comment: @Cracker0dks it makes it simple :) Nightly will probably take a few months but at least it's in the works