# Firefox 37 throwing error when trying to add microphone volume control for WebRTC audio context

Tags: firefox, webrtc, html5-audio, audiocontext

Since firefox 37 I cannot add volume control to the input(microphone), i get the error :

> IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

It works fine on Chrome.

Here is the code sample :

```
var audioContext    = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(); // define audio context
var microphone      = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
var gain            = audioContext.createGain();
var speaker         = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination(gain);
gain.gain.value = 1;
microphone.connect(gain);
gain.connect(speaker);
```

The error is thrown here :

**microphone.connect(gain);**

weirdly it works on firefox nightly.

This error is similar to this stackoverflow :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29550278/1427338)

Related link :
[link on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28598492/1427338)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you use this for microphone?

```
 var microphone      = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource();
```

instead of this

```
 var microphone      = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
```

A microphone is not a destination. It is a source.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think it should be

```
var microphone      = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
```

Here stream is the microphone audio stream. Find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource).

Also check out this [demo](http://mdn.github.io/media-source-buffer/) with elaboration [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource). It is similar to what you are trying. Replace *createMediaElementSource* with *createMediaStreamSource* will work.